# Subclass UITabBarController

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

in apple documentation it said that UITabBarController can only be subclassed in iOS6+, but when i'm running by app in the iOS 5 simulator everything is working great.

how can i be sure that this will work?

I have only an iPad with iOS 6+.

Comment: Can you share that doc link?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: `This class is generally used as-is but` __may be__ `subclassed in iOS 6 and later.`

Comment: yes i know but will it work with ios 5? in the ios5 simulator it works

Comment: Ya it will work. You are overriding `UITabBarController` to support interface orientation in `iOS6` right? . In fact you can extend any class in objective c by adding `categories`. It will not cause any error

Comment: No i'm changing the location of the tabBar.